# Base Map using ggplot2 for any country

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to choose a specific country (like Seychelles) to create a base map in background using `map_data()` function in ggplot2. Is there another function to retrieve polygones of countries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check `maps` package

```
maps::map('world', regions = "Seychelles")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get a higher resolution map using the `rnaturalearth` package:

```r
library(rnaturalearth)
library(dplyr)

ne_countries(scale = 10, returnclass = 'sf') %>%
  filter(geounit == "Seychelles") %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(fill = "#e0e8a0") +
  ylim(c(-5, -4)) +
  xlim(c(-55, -56)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#8088d0"),
        panel.grid = element_line(size = 0.1))
```

[image]

Comment: doesn't plot anything and asks me to install "rnaturalearthhires" package

Comment: @Andre230 yes, and if you install the `rnaturalearthhires` package it will plot the above image. If you are happy with depicting the Seychelles as a 7-edge polygon, then `maps` is certainly easier.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will use maps, it says can't add map to a ggplot object. is there a way of adding maps to ggplot (to plot some coordinates)?

Comment: You would need to convert the output of `map` (which is a `list` of x values, y values, range and names) into a data frame. Something like `ggplot(as.data.frame(maps::map('world', regions = "Seychelles")[c('x', 'y')])) + geom_polygon(aes(x, y))`. This is honestly doing it the hard way. It's really easy and looks much better if you use the detailed shapefile data you get from something like `rnaturalearth`, and use the proper map projections this gives you.  You can do `remotes::install_github('https://github.com/ropensci/rnaturalearthhires')` to install the hi res data.